# android: The apps was closed when displaying the searched result in listView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

when my application try to display the searched result, the application was closed like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kof3q.jpg

here is the information showed in logcat

> E/Buffer Error(784): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
>
> E/JSON Parser(784): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
>
> W/dalvikvm(784): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay$LoadAllBooks.doInBackground(SearchResultDisplay.java:82)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay$LoadAllBooks.doInBackground(SearchResultDisplay.java:1)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(784):     ... 4 more
>   11-23 14:24:49.267: W/EGL_emulation(784): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> E/WindowManager(784): Activity com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40dec338 V.E..... R......D 0,0-470,144} that was originally added here
>
> E/WindowManager(784): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40dec338 V.E..... R......D 0,0-470,144} that was originally added here
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay$LoadAllBooks.onPreExecute(SearchResultDisplay.java:68)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at com.example.qrandrary.SearchResultDisplay.onCreate(SearchResultDisplay.java:53)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at a
>   ndroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> E/WindowManager(784):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

here is the code:

```
public class SearchResultDisplay extends ListActivity {
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> booksList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_books = "http://127.0.0.1/qrandrary/quickSearch.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_BOOKS = "books";
private static final String TAG_BID = "bid";
private static final String TAG_BNAME = "bname";
private static final String TAG_AUTHORS = "authors";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
private static final String TAG_PUBLISHER = "publisher";
ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
// products JSONArray
JSONArray books = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_resultlist_view);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    new LoadAllBooks().execute();
}

class LoadAllBooks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchResultDisplay.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Books. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String keyword = extras.getString("keyword");
        url_all_books = url_all_books + "?keyword=" + keyword;
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_books, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Books: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                books = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BOOKS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = books.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String bid = c.getString(TAG_BID);
                    String bName = c.getString(TAG_BNAME);
                    String authors = c.getString(TAG_AUTHORS);
                    String publisher = c.getString(TAG_PUBLISHER);
                    String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_BID, bid);
                    map.put(TAG_BNAME, bName);
                    map.put(TAG_AUTHORS, authors);
                    map.put(TAG_PUBLISHER, publisher);
                    map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    booksList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                BookListViewAdapter adapter = new BookListViewAdapter(SearchResultDisplay.this,R.layout.search_result_item, rowItems);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
}
}

public class BookListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public BookListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }


    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtBid;
        TextView txtBname;
        TextView txtAuthors;
        TextView txtPublisher;
        TextView txtStatus;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtBid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bid);
            holder.txtBname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bName);
            holder.txtAuthors = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.authors);
            holder.txtPublisher = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            holder.txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtBid.setText(rowItem.getbId());
        holder.txtBname.setText(rowItem.getbName());
        holder.txtAuthors.setText(rowItem.getAuthors());
        holder.txtPublisher.setText(rowItem.getPublisher());
        holder.txtStatus.setText(rowItem.getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }
}
public class RowItem {
    private int bId;
    private String bName;
    private String authors;
    private String status;
    private String publisher;
    public RowItem(int bId, String bName, String authors, String status,
            String publisher) {
        this.bId = bId;
        this.bName = bName;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.status = status;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    public int getbId() {
        return bId;
    }
    public void setbId(int bId) {
        this.bId = bId;
    }
    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }
    public void setbName(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }
    public String getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
    public void setAuthors(String authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }
    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }



}

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

What is the problem in my application?

Answer (score 0):

I think what problem in JSON that receives your application. You could check log to find out what isn't correct in JSON object.